# Issue with foreign key relationship

Tags: sql-server, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table where primary key is a composite key: P_ID and [YEAR]

```
Table1
_______
P_ID  int
YEAR   nvarchar
FIELD1
```

and another table:

```
Table2
__________
P_ID int
PDate  datetime
Year  nvarchar
Field2
```

In Table1 P_ID is not unique, in order to get a unique record one needs to combine P_ID and Year. In Table2 the unique identifier would be a combination of P_ID and PDate field where PDate is a first day of each month (ex: 9/1/2015), so there are 12 records per each P_ID.

Neither of the tables have any constraints, so I wanted to create a primary key for Table1 on P_ID and Year. For Table2 I wanted to make P_ID and PDate the primary key. Now the problem is I cannot create a foreign key in Table2 that would link it to Table1, since P_ID is a part of composite key. What would be the best way to join those two tables together or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: If you were using Oracle you could create a materialised view, something like SELECT DISTINCT P_ID from Table1.  Then you could create a foreign key constraint based on that.  But you are using SQL Server, so this isn't an option.  I would redesign the database if at all possible.

Comment: not sure I can do that... How would you redesign it? Any ideas in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.  The following code was run on SQL Server 2008 r2.

```
use tempdb;

CREATE TABLE T1 (
  P_ID int not null,
  Year char(4) not null,
  Field1 varchar(50) null
  );

ALTER TABLE T1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, Year);


CREATE TABLE T2 (
  P_ID int not null,
  PDate datetime not null,
  Year char(4) not null,
  Field2 varchar(50) null
  );

ALTER TABLE T2 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_2 PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, PDate);

ALTER TABLE T2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2_1 FOREIGN KEY (P_ID, Year)
    REFERENCES T1 (P_ID, Year);

GO


INSERT T1 VALUES (1, 2015, 'abc'); -- Will Succeed
INSERT T1 VALUES (2, 2015, 'bcd'); -- Will Succeed

INSERT T2 VALUES (1, '1/1/2015', 2015, 'xyz'); -- Will Succeed
INSERT T2 VALUES (3, '1/1/2015', 2015, 'xyz'); -- Will Fail

SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

Comment: creating Fk constraint gave me an error: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_2_1"

Comment: That will be because you have data that breaks the referential integrity.  Your best bet would be to find this and fix it, e.g. SELECT T2.* FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.P_ID = T2.P_ID AND T1.[YEAR] = T2.[YEAR] WHERE T1.P_ID IS NULL;